# ASP.NET MVC 4, MongoDB, implementing login

Tags: mongodb, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4

I've used MongoDB before, but never with ASP.NET MVC.

Currently, I'm stuck trying to implement authentication for system which is going to use exclusively MongoDB (so, I don't have the option of leaving the users table to a SQL database).

Now, I figured a solution would be implementing my own Membership provider. However, that requires quite a lot of code. And, since it is related to security, it is not wise to reivent the wheel if I can avoid it.

Coming from Rails, it would be rather simple to just add something like Devise, set it up to use MongoDB and call it a day. I couldn't find anything similar for ASP.NET MVC - I am not sure if it is an uncommon use case, or if my Google-Fu is inadequate.

I don't need anything fancy -just the ability to create users, check their credentials and protect controllers from being called from unauthenticated users. Are there any packages that could solve my problem?

Comment: which package you have use to authenticate users in MongoDb? since i'm also trying to figure out similar issue

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/osuritz/MongoDB.Web

A collection of ASP.NET providers (caching, membership, profiles, roles, session state, web events) for MongoDB.

Comment: There are several forks of it, most of them with more recent commits. Have you used any of them?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use https://extmongomembership.codeplex.com/ as this is newer provider that was presented in ASP.NET MVC4. And it contin eve more features (for instance permissions system if need)